# Android and QPluginLoader problems

Tags: android, c++, qt

i compliled my Qt app to android using qt 5.2.1, everthing goes well until i try to load a plugin in the app. Let me explain, i have an app, that uses several plugin created by my self using the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE macro. The app is working well in linux/windows.
When a i try to load plugin using `pluginLoader.instance();` the method `pluginLoader.errorString();` raise the fallow error:

> D/Qt      (17850): sources\mainWindows.cpp:393 (void
>   coreVLab::vlMainWindows::loadPlugin(QString)): "The shared library was
>   not found."

The location used to pass to the plugin path is

> assets:/libExampleQtListener_d.so

I of course i 100% secured the plugin is located in this path..
Some help need...thanks for reading and sorry for the English.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
void copyPlugin(const QDir &dir, const QString&file) {
    auto dataLocation = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation);
    QString destPluginName = dataLocation + "/" + file;
    if(QFile(destPluginName).exists()) {
        return;
    }
    QFile sourcePlugin(QFileInfo(dir,file).filePath());
    sourcePlugin.copy(destPluginName);
    QFile destPlugin(destPluginName);
    destPlugin.setPermissions(QFileDevice::ExeOwner | QFileDevice::ExeUser | QFileDevice::ExeOther | QFileDevice::ExeGroup |
                                      QFileDevice::ReadOwner | QFileDevice::ReadUser | QFileDevice::ReadOther | QFileDevice::ReadGroup |
                                      QFileDevice::WriteOwner| QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::WriteOther | QFileDevice::WriteGroup);
}

void copyPlugins(const QDir &dir, const QStringList &filesList) {
    for(const auto file : filesList) {
        copyPlugin(dir,file);
    }
}
#endif
```

After that i just load plugins from new location.

When you add files to assets Qt changes permissions.